# tvOS icon not showing

Tags: resources, icons, tvos, xcasset, launchimage

I have created a tvOS app and I have added images for the Top Shelf, both icons, and the Launch Image. When I compile and run the app in the Simulator those images don't show up. It's like the OS can't find the images and I don't understand why.

The xcassets file is in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase and it's a target member. The "Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name" under build settings is set correctly. The images are in png format and of the appropriate size.

Any ideas why the images are not being displayed?

EDIT: In case it is relevant the project is using CocoaPods with a privet Pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the app from the simulator, clean the project, remove the images, add the images back, and build and run the application again.

Comment: That is a good guess but doesn't appear to be the case. I took the LaunchImage from my app and put it in a demo app from Apple and it worked just fine. As far as the icons go the only image that can't have an alpha channel is the back most layer. I don't know about the top shelf image.

Comment: @ChrisHorsfield have you deleted the app from the simulator, cleaned the project, removed the images, readded the images, and tried installing the application again?

Comment: Holy crap that worked. The top shelf image now sows.

Answer (score 14):

In Xcode 11, there is a bug with tvOS app icons. To solve it, rename `App Icon & Top Shelf Image` or `Brand Assets` in the Assets to `AppIcon`. In the project settings make sure this is also selected as app icon.

Comment: You just saved my day. You are awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even changing the build settings to match the "Brand Assets" folder name did not work, but this did.

Comment: Its been couple of weeks i have been searching for any response for this bug. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, I had wondered if that would work.  It did.  Saved me a lot of trouble.  Annoying thing is that if you create a new tvOS asset catalog and try to create a new icon set, the name is defaulted such that it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset the Simulator
2. Command + Shift + Alt + K, to clean you project
3. Build and Run

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was including the asset catalog in the tvOS target. Not sure why it wasn't included by default.